# Не получается импортировать библиотеку в Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle, зависимости

При попытке запуска проекта проявляется ошибка:

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Импорт выглядит так:

```
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha'
```

Comment: jitpack добавили в список зависимостей на уровне приложения?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, заменил на implementation 'com.mysugr.MPAndroidChart:MPAndroidChart:3.1.0-mysugr-1' и эта проблема исчезла